# PHP & MySQL - What is the logic on how to use mysqldump to backup your database and send it to an email address using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how would I go about using mysqldump to backup my database and send the data to an email address using PHP?

Comment: is it such a tiny database that it can be sent over email?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel then how should i store it or send it in parts using email?

Comment: use FTP or something more reliable. and not PHP but some shell script run by cron

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, you just can't insult PHP and not explain why PHP is not reliable.

Comment: Ahahahaha! If I tell you not to eat a soup with fork, I'd insult a fork then.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, no its just common sense to eat soup with a spoon.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This require [phpmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/):

```
<?php

   require("class.phpmailer.php");

   header("Content-type: text/plain");

   // --- MySQL et path --------------------------------------------------------
   $mysql_host     = 'XXXXXXX';
   $mysql_username = 'XXXXXXX';
   $mysql_password = 'XXXXXXX';
   $mysql_db       = 'XXXXXXX';
   $mail_to1        = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
   $mail_to1_name   = 'XXXXXXXXX';
   $mail_to2        = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
   $mail_to2_name   = 'XXXXXXXXX';
   // --------------------------------------------------------------------------


   $fname = '' . $mysql_db . '_' . strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') . '.sql.gz';
   echo "Backing up to $fname\n";
   system('mysqldump --host=' . $mysql_host . ' --user=' . $mysql_username . 
        ' --password=' . $mysql_password . ' ' . $mysql_db . ' | gzip >' . 
        $fname);

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->SetLanguage("en", "language/");
   $mail->From = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
   $mail->FromName = 'Webmaster';
   $mail->AddAddress($mail_to1, $mail_to1_name);
   $mail->AddAddress($mail_to2, $mail_to2_name);
   $mail->WordWrap = 50;         // set word wrap to 50 characters
   $mail->IsHTML(false);         // set email format to plain text
   $mail->Subject = '[XXX] Backup MySQL - ' . strftime('%x %X');
   $mail->Body    = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

   if (!$mail->AddAttachment($fname)) // add attachments
   {
      echo 'Erreur : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . "\n";
      $mail->Body .= "\n" . 'Erreur : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   }

   if (!$mail->Send())
   {
      echo 'Message could not be sent. <p>';
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      exit;
   }

   echo 'Message has been sent';
   unlink($fname);
   exit;

?>
```

Used on some BDD (the host only provides some php script jobs, no cron) and mail are sent to gmail. You can add a `-9` to gzip or use bzip for better compression.

Comment: I have to admit that this answer is quite sensible, unlike 99% of answers here.

Comment: on this line return a problem, can't access the server.. I don not know why...    system('mysqldump --host=' . $mysql_host . ' --user=' . $mysql_username . ' --password=' . $mysql_password . ' ' . $mysql_db . ' | gzip >' . $fname);

Comment: Mostly because you `mysqldump` can't access the server (no route to the server, bad credentials, ...)